# Reversing MongoDB Migration to unset fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Say I'm trying to unset all foo fields in a Collection where foo:'bar'.

`Collection.update({foo:'bar'}, {$unset:{foo:1}});`

I want to try using https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/migrations.

My question is about how one would go about reverting that in a `down` function.

The selector for `{foo:'bar'}` won't match on anything anymore as those fields are removed.

The only thing I can think of is something like

#1. Save all `_ids` somewhere first

```
const idsOfFoosToBeUnset = Collection.find({foo:'bar'},{fields: {_id:1}}).fetch().map(doc => doc._id);
fs.writeFileSync('idsOfFoosToBeUnset.json', JSON.stringify(idsOfFoosToBeUnset), 'utf-8');
```

Actual `down` function

```
const idsToBeReset = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('idsOfFoosToBeUnset.json', 'utf-8');
Collection.update({_id: {$in:idsToBeReset }}, {$set: {foo: 'bar'}});
```

I'm just not a fan of having to save the `_ids` somewhere and then having to re-import in the `down` function.

Anybody else think of something cleaner?

Comment: As your case demonstrates, there just are some migrations that cannot be reversed (typically when removing some information). Unless you archive that information elsewhere for the sake of potential reversal. Most of the time, we just make do with db backup.